# Sphinx and argparse - autodocumenting command line scripts?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, argparse

I'm building a Python package, and using Sphinx to create the docs. Aside from my package code, I also include a lot of command line Python scripts, which use argparse. I was wondering if there is a way to get Sphinx to autodocument these scripts? The end goal would be a pretty-printed list of scripts, with the associated help print, arguments and options. And to be clear, I'm looking for a pre-existing way to do this, not a way to implement this myself.

This isn't as specific of a question as I usually ask on S.O., if there is a more appropriate S.E. site to post this question, let me know.

Comment: Unrelated, but might be helpful. Check plac package on PyPI.

Comment: Don't think it helps me with this, but interesting, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`sphinxcontrib.programoutput`](http://packages.python.org/sphinxcontrib-programoutput/) to include the help messages from the command line in your documentation.

This is not specific to `argparse` but can be used to document any script printing help messages to the command line.

Answer (score 31):

Use sphinx-argparse extension:

http://sphinx-argparse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Excellent. Is there a way to have the "usage" block treated differently? For me, having it as a literal block isn't quite right.

Comment: And while I'm at it, it would be nice of the output for options matched what `.. option::` produces: flags only (no default indicated), aligned all the way to the left with less indentation for the description, and changing the first letter to caps and adding a period at the end if one is not already there (since the idiom for `--help` is to omit these and use all lowercase). Also perhaps flag entries that match the help help output more closely (e.g. `-cols [COL [COL ...]]` rather than just `cols`), since all the text is written in that context.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`sphinxcontrib.autoprogram`](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-autoprogram/). `pip install sphinxcontrib-autoprogram`, then put

```
extensions += ['sphinxcontrib.autoprogram']
```

in your `conf.py`. To document command `cli.py` by importing `cli` with the argparse `parser` object `parser` (which can be a Python expression, like a function `get_parser()`), use

```
.. autoprogram:: cli:parser
   :prog: cli.py
```