# ReadTheDocs Import Error from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I am having trouble with readthedocs autodocs - the build completes but my documentation is empty for each class.

Looking at the build information, seem to be getting a Syntax Error which causes a few warning:

```
print(clean_sample, file=open(new_fname, 'w'))
```

However, this does not seem like a bug to me at all.

Here is the build information
https://readthedocs.org/projects/medembed/builds/7108142/

My file structure is:

```
MedEmbed/
  docs/
    build/
    source/
      code.rst
      conf.py
      index.rst
  medembed/
    __init.py
    main.py
    transformer.py
    dataset.py
    embedding.py
```

As such I added within conf.py:

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../medembed'))`

I could really appreciate some advice please

EDIT: Python3 Sphinx solved the above.

Now, I am importing a constant `DIR_PROCESSED` from **init.py**

For some reason Sphinx does not like this:

```
from medembed import DIR_PROCESSED
ImportError: No module named 'medembed
```

The build failed:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/medembed/builds/7108602/

Comment: You're probably using python2 to run Sphinx, despite the fact that your project is using python 3. Are you using a virtual environment? If no, you probably want to install sphinx for python 3 with `pip3 install sphinx`.

Comment: @julienc Thanks, I was not using a virtual environment. Would you mind looking at the latest issue please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were multiple things that were not working correctly with Sphinx.

- `code.rst`: you should indicate the package name for every module you want to run `autodoc` on:

  ```
  .. automodule:: medembed.main
     :members:

  .. automodule:: medembed.dataset
     :members:

  .. automodule:: medembed.embedding
     :members:

  .. automodule:: medembed.transformer
     :members:
  ```
- `conf.py`: the path you want to add to `SYSPATH` is the path to the package's parent directory, not the package itself:

  ```
  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
  ```
- `main.py`, `dataset.py`, `embedding.py`, `transformer.py`: you should use relative imports instead of absolute ones, when importing stuff from within your package:

  ```
  -from transformer import Transformer
  +from .transformer import Transformer

  -from medembed import DIR_PROCESSED
  +from . import DIR_PROCESSED

  -from dataset import TxtDataset, XMLDataset
  -from embedding import Embedding
  +from .dataset import TxtDataset, XMLDataset
  +from .embedding import Embedding
  ```
- `main.py`: don't add `if __name__ == "__main__"` directive: the code would be executed when analyzed by Sphinx, and this is not what you want (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34570114/2679935)). In fact, sphinx forbids this and returns a warning if you try:

  ```
  WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'medembed.main'; the module executes module level statement and it might call sys.exit().
  ```

  What you should do instead is create a `main.py` in the parent directory that won't be analyzed by sphinx:

  ```
  from medembed.main import main

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

  I'm using an absolute import here as this `main.py` file is not in the `medembed` package.

I created a pull request on your repo with all these changes:
https://github.com/isaacsultan/MedEmbed/pull/4