# How to generate CLI documentation from python code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am using the `argparse` package and I am interested in generating documentation like the `--help` command does, but in HTML/LaTeX or any of the usual formats. I am using sphinx now for package reference creation, so an extension to that would be the best solution.

Comment: Take a look at http://sphinxcontrib-autoprogram.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. I wonder why it did not show up in my searches so far... Please post it as an answer so that I can accept

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10886841/407651